# JS library that displays PDF as flipbooks

Tags: gratis, library, javascript, pdf, pdf-viewer

### The goal

I'm looking for a JavaScript library or plug-in that I can use to view regular PDF files as flipbooks like the one below:

[image: PDF flipbook viewer]

### What have I tried

I found many solutions that can convert PDFs and solutions that can create flipbooks but from HTML or other input.

### Requirements

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to create a site where users just upload their regular PDFs and those will be displayed as flipbooks so they don't have to convert the PDFs themselves.

The solutions doesn't have to be open source but it has to be free and shouldn't put any labels, popups, etc. that guides to a "full version".

Comment: Similar thread on this site: [PDF as flip book on website](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/pdf-as-flip-book-on-website), updated 2020

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Responsive FlipBook Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/responsive-flipbook-plugin/2372863) (a CodeCanyon WordPress plugin) before and it worked well. It has an additional extension that allows PDFs to be uploaded and automatically made into a flipbook - so no coding required.

The question wasn't specific, but when you say 'users', do you need some way to manage these users or is uploading PDFs open to anyone that visits the site?