# PDF as flip book on website

Tags: web-apps, pdf, reading

Our organization would like to take a PDF of a document we have created and host it as a flip book on our website or link to it from our website on another service.

We do not plan to make any more flip books in the near future. We would like to be able to avoid advertisements which go with the free services. We would also like to be able to add our logo and some hotspots linking to other media. Additionally, while I will be in charge of this project for the next two months to get it off the ground and feel comfortable learning a new platform, my replacement may not be able to handle that as well so it should be a relatively easy tool to learn.

Can you recommend software, preferably open source, which could accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you define "flip book"? If you mean a series of images that appear to animate, then I suggest linking to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_book). Or do mean a series of boards to be printed for a sales presentation or [storyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storyboard)?

Comment: I personally recommend [issuu](https://issuu.com) for PDF flipping on the web. There is also a mobile app if you are interested.

Comment: @Basil Bourque, Flip book is a term used for electronic applications that simulate the usage of a printed magazine, where you can drag a page to turn to the next one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option is to use [Heyzine](https://heyzine.com), it's a pdf to flipbook converter.
You can create a flip book and embed it on your site without having to learn anything and without plugins. If you don't want to link external sites, it also allows you to download the html flipbook.

In case you need to convert more than one PDF, it has an API to make conversions with a jquery plugin or simple links, making it very easy. It's not open source but it's free, unlike most of the flipbook converters out there.

Here are some examples of how it will look like and it's also very customizable:

[Magazine flipbook](https://heyzine.com/flip-book/2598fbb5ac.html)

[Catalog slideshow](https://heyzine.com/flip-book/2683af5c6b.html)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be  what your looking for , free light weight

http://turnjs.com

Answer (score 0):

PDFTron [WebViewer](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/index.html) can do this.

[Flip book sample](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/samples/flipbook/index.html)

This is a paid solution, and not open source, though all the code you need to modify the user interface is made available with a license.

You convert your PDF to WebViewer XOD format (subset of XPS format) and the file will be viewable on any computer/device with any modern browser (HTML5 Canvas).

Answer (score 0):

As for a recommendation, I've just finished my 14 day trial on https://www.paperturn.com/us (had way too much time on my hands between Xmas and New Years Eve)

Was quite easy to use, and I must say, very nice people on the chat to help out, if I didn't find the answer in the guide.

No ads during the trial (added bonus right there) and I'm actually thinking of paying the 15$ a month for the basic. I've looked a bit on the Pro version (think its 30$ or something), and might even do that sometime in the future!

Answer (score 0):

When reviewing options for a program like this you need to take into account a couple of things.

Avoid Flash based programs unless you are only interested in Desktop viewers.

Focus on what your user need to see, and not only the flip effect, that can be catchy but sometimes turns the publication unreadable only "viewable".

Sayed that I would incline for an html5 based application.

Forget your requirement of adding a logo. Add the logo on the publication itself.

Here is an Html5 JavaScript library that does this: http://www.turnjs.com/

You do not use a pdf directly but some images, or screen "captures" but that can be easily solved.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting solution: [Publuu.com](https://publuu.com)

Hi, maybe not a free solution but with 14 days trial and lowest price is quite cheep.

I've tried because I was intrigued by the features it offers and its good price. Finally I decide to use it longer ;) because ... its simplicity.
Currently we’re now replacing all PDFs with flipbooks (offers / catalogs / brochures).

Here you can see examples: Flipbook Examples.
But it's best to set up a free account and test it on your own.

Btw you can easily generate embed code that allows to put your flipbook on page.