# Converting pdf into HTML5 that the user can turn pages on

Tags: pdf, html, file-converter

I am looking for a program that converts a pdf into HTML5 (or flash)

that the end user can turn pages on as if it were a paper book.

Example:

http://www.caminetto.hu/hu/etlapunk.html

Sound is a plus but not necessary.

Is there an open source solution for this on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

[**PDFTron WebViewer**](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/index.html), [my recommendation for a flip book](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/34617/24376), applies to this question also.

You could certainly add sound.

The code is not open source, but all the JavaScript/CSS code for the user interface is included in the library, which you can modify and use when you purchase a license.

There is a [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pdfnet-webviewer) that shows examples of customizing.